# Placing two trailing icons in ListTile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to place two icons, side by side on the "trailing" side of a ListTile. I tried adding a Row widget with the two icons inside, but it completely messed up the layout of the entire ListTile, making it unusable. Is there any way to expand the space allocated for the trailing part?

Here's the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.play_arrow,),
          title: Text("This is a title"),
          subtitle: Text("This is subtitle"),
          trailing: Row(          
            children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.flight),
            Icon(Icons.flight_land)
          ]),
        )
      ]
    ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: What you mean by - 'completely messed up the layout of the entire ListTile' ? - share your Code. you might be doing something weird.

Comment: agree with @anmol.majhail . also if you can share screenshot

Comment: How about just calling in a function to return a custom child Widget for the listview? I'd suggest using ListView.builder()

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Adding `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to the Row() instance fixes the issue.

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Even though I don't get why the ListTile widget behaves like this having a row in trailing...

Answer (score 95):

You can simply use `Wrap` in `trailing`

```
ListTile(
  title: Text("This is my ListTile"),
  trailing: Wrap(
    spacing: 12, // space between two icons
    children: <Widget>[
      Icon(Icons.call), // icon-1
      Icon(Icons.message), // icon-2
    ],
  ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: How to use it for columns? I would like to use the up arrow, text, down arrow to the right side of the list tile.

Comment: @TipVisor Please ask as a separate question, it is difficult to provide any help without seeing your code and how exactly you want things to be.

Comment: Why does this work? What is wrap doing that row without mainAxisSize cant do? Tbh I dont event get the MainAxisSize.min solution. Can someone maybe explain what flutter is doing behind the scenes there?

Comment: I would add `crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,`

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I want the icon vertically.

Answer (score 32):

Try this code. I think this is working correctly:

```
trailing: FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.flight),
            Icon(Icons.flight_land),
          ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Using Wrap() is a lot less typing :-)

Comment: FittedBox takes lot of trailing space.

Comment: This is best solution if you use different widget because you will get a nice vertical alignment

Comment: This is the best solution, because wrap is not working in case you use Column instead row.

Answer (score 1):

I took advantage of the FittedBox solution left above and solved my problem by displaying a TextButton and an IconButton when the screen is in landscape and when in portrait mode, only IconButton

```
trailing: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 480
                      ? FittedBox(
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              TextButton(
                                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                  // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                  primary: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
                                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                onPressed: () => onRemove(tr.id),
                                child: const Text('Excluir'),
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
                                onPressed: () => onRemove(tr.id),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      : IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                          color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
                          onPressed: () => onRemove(tr.id),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Given negative value to `spacing` did the trick:

```dart
   trailing: Wrap(
            spacing: -16,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.delete,
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

[image]