# Flutter not rendering page

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, frameworks, mobile-development

I am new to flutter and was not able to view my output eventhough there was no error in the code.

Here is what i was developing:
[image: what i want to develop]

Now the error was in the list that is in the center.
Here are 2 codes and I want to know why one works and other doesnt:

1. Code that does not work:
   [image: Code that does not work]
2. Code that works:
   [image: Code that works]

I am trying out multiple ways to create the list but it was a bit nerve wracking when the code was not even rendering and had no error (according to VS code)

Comment: Try setting `Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,` this way you can tell Flutter that you want this Row to take as little space as possible.

I advice reading about layout in Flutter docs, as its not trivial [https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout]

Answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548853/placing-two-trailing-icons-in-listtile

Answer (score 0):

You can try ListView.builder with "shrinkWrap: true" property

ListView.builder can't display children without knowing its sizes, so the code in the first screenshot doesn't work.
In the section where your code works, you add Container that adds a size to each element in ListView.